# Reading a CSV file using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm a newbie. I want to get data from the CSV file-the Id and Name fields, but when I run the reading method, I get only 100 lines of an incomprehensible type: "CsvHelper.CsvReaderd__87`1[Program+Product]". I do not know how to get data from CSV, I also cannot understand where the error is.

Although the documentation says that having the same names of properties and CSV headers, you do not need to write additional configurations. However, I get the result specified above. The CSV names match the classes. Link to the documentation:https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

reading method:

```
  {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Product>();
            Console.WriteLine($"{records}");
        }
    }
```

CSV is created without problems, there are two columns with Id and Name with filled rows, there are 100 rows in total:

[image]

method for creating a csv with the Id and Name fields:

```
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(products);
    }
```

the entire code:

```
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Product(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
    public const string PathToDoc = "C:/Users/Saint/Desktop/TaskRetail/yml.xml";


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1sSR9kWifwjIP5qFWcyxGCxN0-MoEd_oo?alt=media&key=AIzaSyBsW_sj1GCItGBK0vl8hr9zu1I1vTI1Meo";
        string savePath = @"C:\Users\Saint\Desktop\TaskRetail\yml.xml";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFile(url, savePath);

        Research();
    }

    public static void Research()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(PathToDoc);
        var xmlDoc = document.SelectNodes("/yml_catalog/shop/offers/offer");
        var count = xmlDoc.Count;
        var products = new List<Product>();
        Console.WriteLine($"Offers count: {count}");
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var element = xmlDoc.Item(i);
            var id = int.Parse(element.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value);
            var name = element.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
            var product = new Product(id, name);
            //Console.WriteLine($"Id: {id}, name: {name}");

            products.Add(product);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(products);
            }

         var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = ",", PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Header.ToLower() };
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Saint\\Desktop\\TaskRetail\\file.csv", Encoding.UTF8))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))

        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Product>();

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{record.Id} {record.Name}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file have you read the documents, specifically about reading the file?

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/ says *"The GetRecords<T> method will return an IEnumerable<T> that will yield records"*

Comment: Generally in C# we are quite careful about how we name things, and in turn this is why I tend to point out naming fails I see on SO. The name **GetRecords** implies that multiple things will be returned, i.e. that the result is something that is some kind of collection that you can loop over, and contains more than one *record*.. From this you can infer that you must treat it as such. If it was just returning one thing, as your code is trying to use it as, it would be called GetRecord

Comment: In turn, I'd like to point out that your method name "Research" is quite poor; research is a noun and a verb, but your method doesnt appear to implement that action of performing research. I implore you to think more arefully about the names you give your methods, and consequently, read more carefully the names that library developers have chosen to give their methods; it should help the person who uses it know exactly what it does. Name your own methods better, and demand that other people name theirs better so that all the code becomes more readable and self descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `GetRecords()` does return an object of type `IEnumerable`,
you have to iterate over your records to print each one of them:

```cs
foreach(var record in records)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{record.Id} {record.Name}");
}
```

Furthermore you have to access each property you want to print individually.
Another option would be to override the `ToString()` method in your `Product` class.

**EDIT**

The initial problem wasn't the correct printing of the values but the parsing of the file as I learned from this comment:

> CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: 'Header with name 'id'[0] was not found. Header with name 'name'[0] was not found.

To tackle this problem one have to make sure that the delimiter character is set correctly. This can be enforced in the config object of the CsvHelper. Furthermore to avoid casing errors the configuration can be set to ignore the casing of the headers:

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
{ 
   Delimiter = ",", // Enforce ',' as delimiter
   PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Header.ToLower() // Ignore casing
};

using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I got an exception: "CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException: 'Header with name 'id'[0] was not found.
Header with name 'name'[0] was not found." , because the records variable gets: "{CsvHelper.CSVReader<GetRecords>d__87<Program.Product>}

Comment: Which separator char is used in your csv file? "," or ";"? Try setting it explicitly to the one you are using before reading the records like `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";`

Comment: most likely it should be", " but I can't use in my code csv.Configuration.Delimiter, due to the CS0200 exception.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that this changed. You have to define this with a configuration object: `var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture){Delimiter = ","};` and pass it to the reader like this: `using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config)){...}`

Comment: I made changes to the lower code, unfortunately the edits did not help, the record gets an error: "CsvHelper.Exception HeaderValidationException: "The header with the name "id" [0] was not found.The header with the name 'name'[0] was not found."

Comment: One more thing you could try is adding following line to the config object after you define the delimiter: `PrepareHeaderForMatch = header => header.Header.ToLower()`. This will make CsvHelper ignore the casing of your csv file headers.

Comment: It worked, but I get a lot of duplicates. However, I realized my mistake: I had to understand the configuration, I did not understand this.

Comment: I extended my initial answer with the final solution.